# Reflexivity axiom for inferring functional dependencies

Tags: database-theory

As you know there are three Armstrong's Axioms for inferring all the functional dependencies on a relational database. (X, Y and Z are set of attributes)

1. **Reflexivity**: *If X ⊆ Y, then Y → X*
2. **Augmentation**: *If X → Y, then XZ → YZ for any Z*
3. **Transitivity**: *if X → Y and Y → Z, then X → Z*

I understand the augmentation and transitivity for example if we had such schema:

SOME_SCHEMA(a, b, c, d)

with such functional dependencies:

1. a → b
2. b → c

By using augmentation we could get *ac → bc* or by using transitivity we could get *a → c* and much more, however I am not sure how to infer more functional dependencies using reflexivity axiom? What does it really mean that some attribute is a subset of some other attribute?

Could you show me an example using my schema or creating your own, please?

Thank you in advance!

*P.S. Not sure what tag I should use for this question, feel free to change it and remove this line.*

Comment: This should probably go on the Mathematics site. It's really a math question, not a database question. I think.

Comment: @JonSeigel Isn't it used to remove redundancy? If it is  then database administrators should be able to use it (if not using other methods).

Comment: I'm pretty sure questions about normalization are on-topic at stackoverflow.com. That's not to say they're off-topic here, but I think it's expecting a bit much for novice web developers to look on the mathematics site for answers to questions about normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ab → a means that if two tuples in a relation have the same values for the attribute a then they have the same values for both attributes a and b. This seems trivial but it cannot be deduced from the *Augmentation axiom* and *Transitivity axiom*. So if you have a relation with attributes a,b,c you can deduce functional dependencies like

a→a
ab→a
abc→ac

without knowing any additional functional dependency on abc

Comment: ah now i see why it's called trivial :D

Answer (score 4):

"What does it really mean that some attribute is a subset of some other attribute?"

It means nothing.  Functional dependencies exist between **SETS** of attributes.

Whenever the treatment is supposed to be formal and precise (as in, e.g., when stating the very definition of the axioms), that's how X,Y and Z are supposed to be interpreted.

Unfortunately, people tend to always write down concrete examples of FD's without making the **SET** property explicit.  As in, e.g., AB->C, where A,B and C are **attributes**.  Formally, that should actually be {A B} -> {C}, but those braces don't add very much.

And your formulation of the augmentation axiom is incorrect precisely on that count.  If X,Y and Z are **sets** of attributes, then the only correct formulation of the augmentation axiom is

X -> Y   ===>   (X UNION Z) -> (Y UNION Z)

The reflexivity axiom provides a formal definition of what it means to be a **trivial** FD.  The various normal forms are defined in terms of **nontrivial** FDs, hence it must be pinned down what that means exactly.  The reflexivity axiom does that.

Comment: Also, if I recall my college math correctly, one of the reasons for using capital letters in this context is that they're supposed to represent sets themselves. So loosely "A->B" means "the set of attributes named 'A' determines the set of attributes named 'B'". I think this is just a slightly different way of saying what you just said.

Comment: well yeah it was written that XZ actually means X union Z but it's usually ignored